# Cant get back to windows after uninstalling ubuntu

Tags: grub2, windows, uninstall, bios, detect

I have a surface pro 3 so I thought about dual booting it with Ubuntu, every thing went fine but I didn't like it because it had some bugs and I couldn't get the type cover to work so I decided to delete it.

Secure boot is off and hibernation is off.

Installation:

- shrunk main partition (windows)
- create a 20GB partition
- reboot with Ubuntu USB
- installed along side windows
- done

Note: I did not install rEFInd as a replacement EFI boot loader because I decided to delete Ubuntu before completing the whole installation.

Uninstallation:

- booted into windows 8
- entered disk manger and deleted Ubuntu partition, it became 2 partitions 11.7GB and 7.3GB I deleted both of them.
- rebooted the device and I got GNU GRUB 2.2, as I understood from searching its grub rescue 2.2
- stuck on GRUB

What I tried to do:

- changing the root > root not found
- set root='hd1' ,  chainloader +1 > error ( I don't remember what it was exactly)
- other commands doesn't seem to work since its a rescue prompt.
- changed bootload to USB>SSD
- booted with windows USB but the BIOS wont detect it

Now I rebooted with Ubuntu USB and I can install/try Ubuntu, I installed it and after the installation was complete it took me back to the bios and asked me again if I want to install or try Ubuntu(Weird).

Anyways, now I have access to Ubuntu but I want to go back to windows, I don't mind losing all the file on windows I just want a stable device.

Is there anyway I can make the BIOS detect the windows USB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: If it's UEFI, the bios should simply have an option to boot windows instead of ubuntu.

Comment: @psusi Ubuntu overwrites Windows 8's UEFI file, in my experience

Comment: @Hellreaver, no, it adds its own, which is one of the major benefits of UEFI: multiple OSes can each install their own boot loader instead of having to replace the existing one.  UEFI firmware normally has a boot options menu that lists any installed OS boot loaders, as well as any on removable media.  There is of course, one default, and when you install Ubuntu, it sets itself as the default, but typical uefi firmware provides a menu to choose a non default option.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand, now on your disk drive you got the windows partition but can't boot into it. 
Boot into ubuntu live CD and download boot-repair
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
It have fixed that problem for me once.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset your firmware to default settings.
2. Then reboot and check your firmware is set for uefi or bios.
3. Create a windows installation usb using rufus utility (select uefi/bios according to your firmware setting during writing the image to usb in rufus )

**Note:If you dont have a windows key then i would recommend you to download windows 10 from Microsft for this procedure.**

4. Set your firmware to boot from usb first.
5. Then reboot and plug in your usb.
6. It will detect the usb (if all steps are done correctly).
7. Boot to usb and install windows after formatting and deleting all the previous partitions and creating new one for fresh installation.